# onError occasionally not called

Tags: rx-java2, reactive

I have an issue with one of my onError handlers occasionally not being called, leaving my application in a kind of lingering state.

This is my code

```
 tokenSubscription = Observable.interval(pluginProperties.getRefreshTokenInterval(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(x -> {
                    ConversationContextV3 contextV3 = (ConversationContextV3) authenticationContext.getConversationContext();
                    refreshAccessToken(contextV3);
                },
                error -> {
                    logger.error("Exception after retrying refreshing session token, will attempt to reconnect");
                    disconnect();
                }
            );
```

When refreshAccessToken() is called it sometimes throws an exception, which is then handled in onError. Below is the expected output. Notice the last to lines.

```
2017-09-04 20:11:27.750 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-82] DEBUG c.danlind.igz.brokerapi.BrokerLogin - Refreshing access token
2017-09-04 20:11:27.798 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-82] ERROR c.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter - Exception when refreshing session token
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 503 Service Unavailable
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
    at com.danlind.igz.ig.api.client.RestAPI.refreshSessionV1(RestAPI.java:778)
    at com.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter.refreshSessionV1(RestApiAdapter.java:281)
    at com.danlind.igz.brokerapi.BrokerLogin.refreshAccessToken(BrokerLogin.java:80)
    at com.danlind.igz.brokerapi.BrokerLogin.lambda$startRefreshAccessTokenScheduler$17(BrokerLogin.java:99)
... (removed some lines for brevity)
2017-09-04 20:11:27.811 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-82] ERROR c.danlind.igz.brokerapi.BrokerLogin - Exception after retrying refreshing session token, disconnecting
2017-09-04 20:11:27.811 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-82] INFO  c.danlind.igz.brokerapi.BrokerLogin - Disconnecting from IG
```

My issue is that sometimes it seems like onError is never called, leaving me with a log output like this:

```
2017-09-04 20:11:27.750 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-82] DEBUG c.danlind.igz.brokerapi.BrokerLogin - Refreshing access token
    2017-09-04 20:11:27.798 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-82] ERROR c.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter - Exception when refreshing session token
    org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 503 Service Unavailable
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
        at com.danlind.igz.ig.api.client.RestAPI.refreshSessionV1(RestAPI.java:778)
        at com.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter.refreshSessionV1(RestApiAdapter.java:281)
        at com.danlind.igz.brokerapi.BrokerLogin.refreshAccessToken(BrokerLogin.java:80)
        at com.danlind.igz.brokerapi.BrokerLogin.lambda$startRefreshAccessTokenScheduler$17(BrokerLogin.java:99)
    ... (removed some lines for brevity)
```

My code feels pretty straight forward, I can't really understand what would cause this "glitch"? Any ideas? Using RxJava 2.10

Comment: Perhaps the log hasn't been flushed to disk at that time? How are you resubscribing?

Comment: There are log entries after but from other components. There is no resubscription, in that sense. Rather a client library will detect that the connection has failed and reconnect, which will create a new observable.

Comment: Is the Spring framework catching the error and rethrowing it? If it isn't, you would see the behavior you are describing.

Comment: I'm catching and rethrowing it myself if that makes sense